# Skeletal/Abstract class just to store shared state?

Tags: java, user-interface, abstract-class

Given an interface for the Strategy pattern like so:

```
public interface Strategy {
  public Output execute(Input input);
  public Output getLastExecutionOutput();
}
```

if I want to store the last execution result of any Strategy implementation is it correct to define an abstract class like this

```
public abstract class AbstractStrategy implements Strategy {
  protected Output lastOutput;
  public abstract Output execute(Input input);
  public abstract Output getLastExecutionOutput();
}
```

so the implementations can inherit this state?

If this is ok then should the abstract class also implement the getLastExecutionOutput method, in which case the field should become private?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO you *can* do this, and there may be situations where this is the most simple solution (for example, when you are forbidden to change the interface in any way), but to my experience a more SOLID approach is *not* to make the `getLastExecutionOutput` part of the strategy interface. That would eliminate the need for the `AbstractStrategy` class at all.

Instead, look at the place (typically a [template method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)) where `execute` is called. It is probably a better idea to let the caller store the last output by itself. The whole idea of the strategy pattern is to separate the parts of "different strategies" from the parts which are *not different* in each strategy. This makes your strategy objects simpler, with a better distribution of responsibilities. The interface in your example assigns each strategy object two mostly unrelated responsibilities (beyond the responsibility for providing the individual strategy code, it has the additional responsibility to cache the last output) and so implies a violation of the [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Assumed you cannot change the interface and must implement the methods above: in this case I would consider to implement this in a slightly different way (I am not a Java guy, so please forgive me any potential syntactical errors):

```
public abstract class CachingStrategy implements Strategy {
  private Output lastOutput;
  public Output execute(Input input)
  {
       lastOutput = executeInternal(input);
       return lastOutput;
  }

  protected abstract Output executeInternal(Input input);

  public Output getLastExecutionOutput()
  {
       return lastOutput;
  }
}
```

Now, when deriving from this class, you have to implement `executeInternal` instead of `execute` in each child class. The notable difference is that your child classes now don't have to provide code any more for setting `lastOutput` correctly, this responsibility is now completely in the `CachingStrategy` class.

As I wrote above, I think this is only the 2nd best solution. When you have two almost equal solutions, one with use of inheritance and one without, as a rule of thumb, try to use the one without inheritance first. Using inheritance here does not seem to be a big problem at a first glance, but think about what might happen when you get additional requirements "for all strategies" like "firing an event whenever execute was called", "caching not only the last output, but also the last input", and so on. The straightforward solution then seems to implement all these new functionalities into your "common base class", which might end up in a big bloat.